# Seeking country boundaries shapefile which is pre-1980?

Tags: geospatial, historical

I am looking for a shapefile with the country boundaries as they were when Czechoslovakia existed as a country.

Is there any online open source resource where I can find historical country boundary shapefiles?

Comment: [Euratlas](https://library.duke.edu/data/sources/euratlas) has country shapefiles for 1800 and 1900. Too bad Czechoslovakia didn't exist until 1918. Here's a couple of sites with lists of historical GIS data: https://library.stanford.edu/rumsey/map-research/historical-gis-data https://guides.library.duke.edu/gisdata/gisdata_historical https://www.gislounge.com/find-gis-data-historical-country-boundaries/

Answer (score 0):

At the world level, the **[historical-basemaps](https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps)** project offers boundaries for many countries/cultural areas from various periods between 123000 BC to 1994, in [geojson format](https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps/tree/master/geojson). There are world maps for 1920, 1938, 1945, and 1960, where Czechoslovakia borders are available.

Note that the project has the following caveat:

> This historical boundaries project aims at providing ready-to-use base
> maps for mapping historical data. It is work in progress: verify the
> maps by comparison to other sources before using in academic work. If
> you see errors, report them in the "issues" section.
>
> If you use the maps, think about giving back by [contributing](https://github.com/aourednik/historical-basemaps/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).